# SOCKS5 Proxy Setup on Debian

Tags: installation, debian, proxy, socks5

Is there a package I can install in debian that will create a SOCKS5 proxy on some port? (preferably with authentication)

I'd like to use this with uTorrent.

If not, how do you setup a socks5 proxy on a server?

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with ssh due the simplicity of it, but if you really prefer to take an alternate route, [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) can act as a SOCKS proxy, and so can [Dante](http://www.inet.no/dante/).

Answer (score 1):

Try an SSH tunnel. There is no setup required on either side*!

To create a tunnel from the client:

```
ssh -D 1234 yourusername@yourserver
```

where 1234 is the port on localhost you want the tunnel to run on,
yourusername is your username on the server,
and yourserver is the server.

Use localhost as the proxy, port 1234 (or whatever you chose above). SSH will automatically tunnel through the server, securely.

*you might not have SSH, in which case, on the server, `aptitude install openssh-server`, and on the client, `aptitude install openssh-client`

Comment: that's one way, but I'd rather something I can use without needing to have SSH